# iPhone 5s Camera Calibration Parameters

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, camera-calibration

I was wondering if anyone out there had any reliable intrinsic or extrinsic parameters they would be willing to share with regards to the iPhone 5s camera? I'm working in OpenCV and would like to undistort my images prior to processing. I have been working on code to calibrate on my own, but the end results are pretty painful at this point. If anyone has any clean c++ links to code I'd appreciate that as well. I've been trying to piecemeal something together from older tutorials, and it's not going so hot.

As I understand, I think I am looking for parameters like fx, fy, cx, cy as well as 5 distortion parameters (k1,k2,k3,r1,r2). Though I know each camera is a unique and beautiful snowflake, I just have to think that as a ballpark there have to be some stable references to these values for this particular camera.

Thank you all for the help over the years.

Comment: Extrinsic parameters have nothing to do with camera spec. They are the  position and orientation relative to some coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the samples folder in the OpenCV directory. I've been using the Python script from there, but of course, there's a [C++ version](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp?rev=3474) as well.

Answer (score 2):

As Adi Shavit said, the extrisic parameters can only be determined relativ so some other coordinate system. Further more I believe that the distortion coefficients are different for each camera chip and there is no general way of knowing them without calibration.